# install software on remote server from the workstation using chef

Tags: chef-infra, google-cloud-platform

new to chef.

Managed to use [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-video-demo-chef) example to create google cloud vm instance and even delete them.

```
(1..2).each do |i|
  # <name of cookbook>_instance will lead to instance.rb . weird.
  google_cloud_instance "#{name_prefix}-#{i}" do
    machine_type 'n1-standard-1'
    zone_name "#{zone_a}"
    boot_disk_image "debian-7-wheezy-v20140408"
    service_account_scopes ["compute", "userinfo.email", "devstorage.full_control"]
    tags ["application-server"]    # TODO take from metadata
    metadata "application-server"=> true, "foo"=>"bar"
    auto_restart true
    on_host_maintenance "TERMINATE"
    # enable turbo mode!
    wait_for false
    # bootstrap attributes
    first_boot_json FIRST_BOOT
    client_rb CLIENT_RB
    validation_pem VALIDATION_PEM
    # auth
    client_email AUTH_EMAIL
    project_id AUTH_PROJECT
    key_location AUTH_KEYPATH
    action :create
  end
  servers << "#{name_prefix}-#{i}"
end
```

Running this code on the `chef-workstation` using

```
chef-client -z -o 'google_cloud::gce-create-service-server'
```

Now, On the machines I've created I want to install software. 
for example `ruby 2.1`, `rabbitmq`, etc..
Do I have to use the chef-server. If not, how? if yes, can I do it using the command line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good place to start learning Chef. The answer to your question is to set a `run_list` key in the first boot JSON with the recipes to run that correspond to what you want the server to do.

More generally, you should check out https://learn.chef.io/ to get started with Chef basics like cookbooks and recipes.

Comment: hi @coderanger, Thank you for your reply. I have learned chef for the past week. Still I'm unsure about the solution. `run_list` is set per node. for example `basic_app_server`. but I want to create several instances of that node  with different names. Can I do That?

Comment: When just starting out, I wouldn't try using the Chef-based provisioning stuffs. Those are generally an advanced-level thing when you are trying to automate large scale stuff like bringing up whole clusters at once. You can check out the [knife-google](https://github.com/chef/knife-google) plugin to create one-off machines or make them through the GCE web UI and use `knife bootstrap`.